# Using PowerShell to extract SharePoint ListItems and Export into CSV

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, group-by, sort-object

I have been trying to export SharePoint List Items in CSV file after applying Group By & Sorting as provided in below PowerShell Script.

```
$dt=$ListItems.GetDataTable()
$go=$dt | Group-Object "ProjectName"
$ad=$go | Sort-Object -Property {$_.Values[0]},{$_.Count} -Descending
$ad | Select-Object -Property {$_.Values[0]},{$_.Count} | Export-CSV "D:\ProjectInfo.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The above code generating an CSV file where "ProjectName & Count" field in output CSV is not in Descending Order as mentioned below.

```
ProjectName-Count
-----------------
Project10-12 
Project11-8 
Project12-5 
Project13-13
```

Instead, output CSV file should generate "ProjectName & Count" field as shown below

```
ProjectName-Count
-----------------
Project13-13 
Project10-12 
Project1-8 
Project12-5
```

Please help me how to export CSV file with an Descending order

Comment: Change `$go | Sort-Object -Property {$_.Values[0]},{$_.Count} -Descending` to `$go | Sort-Object -Property Count -Descending`